# Boot time in 18.04 increased because of wireless card

Tags: boot, wireless, 18.04

According to `dmesg`, my system (Kubuntu 18.04) takes 5 to 15 extra seconds in the boot before the interface "wlp3s0" can authenticate. This makes the boot process longer than needed. Does anyone know what might be the cause, and how to fix it?

I have a Thinkpad T450s, if that can help.

The output of `dmesg | grep wlp` is the following:

```
[    5.008947] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.923565] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    6.027908] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    6.080147] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   11.343907] wlp3s0: authenticate with 9c:d3:6d:b3:bf:64
[   11.349650] wlp3s0: send auth to 9c:d3:6d:b3:bf:64 (try 1/3)
[   11.353323] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   11.354369] wlp3s0: associate with 9c:d3:6d:b3:bf:64 (try 1/3)
[   11.364316] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 9c:d3:6d:b3:bf:64     (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[   11.365762] wlp3s0: associated
[   11.393441] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
```

By the way, disabling IPv6 makes no difference, I've tried.

Comment: What exactly does dmesg say about it? `dmesg | grep wlp`

Comment: @chili555 Edited :)